# How to hide "Start Video Playback" button when autoplaying video in WebView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple WebView rendering an HTML5 page that has video playing in the backdrop.. I set the video to play automatically by

```
browser.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

It works except the "Start Video Playback" button is still there.  When I click the button it does nothing as the video is already playing.. is there any way to hide this button?  I searched and found nothing.

[image]

EDIT: this worked!

```
browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

            browser.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('VideoClipPlayButton').click();"
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you share link to sample stream with this player, I have idea but i have to check it.

Comment: @mwisnicki http://app.singular.live/webchannels/298/onair  there you go.  i dont have control of any code on that website unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to your problem. You just have to add a new Javascript that will turn off the button when the page is loaded . Codes below has been tested and works. I checked in C # but Java is very similar so it must work.

**JAVA**

```
wv.loadUrl("http://app.singular.live/webchannels/298/onair");
wv.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
     {
    //here create new JS find element in page (button) and set visibility to hidden
    wv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('VideoClipPlayButton').style.visibility = 'hidden';");
       }
});
```

**C# (XAMARIN)**

```
    Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
    WebView wv = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
    wv.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    wv.LoadUrl("http://app.singular.live/webchannels/298/onair");
    wv.Settings.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false;
    wv.Settings.PluginsEnabled = true;
    wv.Settings.SetPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.On);
    wv.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    wv.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;


     button.Click  += (s, e) =>
     {
         wv.LoadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('VideoClipPlayButton').style.visibility = 'hidden';");
     };
```

Comment: sweeettt i won't be able to test this till Monday cus I got assigned to a different project, but I promise to look at this Monday and test it out and give you your credit once it works!  thank you soooooo much

Comment: whoops i got excited too fast.  it actually doesn't work.. i debug it and it definitely is going into the onPageFinished function.. but i'm not sure whether it's going in there too fast as the video isn't physically loaded fully at that point.. or the button element isn't 'VideoClipPlayButton' or what.. i gave u the reputation regardless but let me know if you have any other ideas

Comment: i tested it on Xamarin(Android) with c# , try put this JS function on button wait as page load and button show them try function. This event onPageFinishe can to fast fire function, in xamarin i cant find onpagefinished but in android it have to work as we think.

Comment: i'm not using xamarin... i'm using native android.  i'm sorry i'm not really understanding what you're saying.. can you elaborate or maybe show me some code?

Comment: i also updated OP with something i tried.. i'm trying to WebChromeClient equivalent but it makes the whole video turn into the text 'hidden'.. so i think the javascript is incorrect maybe?

Comment: You try  fire this JS function by other event when the page was loaded(full)?

Comment: Yeah it work, the problem is with this onPageFinished, it probably run to fast this function. I have 2 ways. First you can check in loop whether button is visible or second try find something what can check page loaded full.